# Implement Not Equal with Elasticsearch API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How to implement `not equal(!=)` in Elasticsearch. i had tried `RangeQueryFilter`, but when field is string type that can not get infinite value.

Comment: Can you provide a sample query (even in pseudo code) that you wish to build?

Comment: @Val  Assume  `abc` is filter item, i want to find all source that does not contains `abc`.(not analyzed)

Comment: @Val I think `Not` operator API is that i need

Comment: [`not` is deprecated in 2.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-query.html), you should use `must_not` as indicated in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the `bool/must_not` query in order to select "everything but...". For instance the query below will return all documents whose `item` field value is not equal to `"abc"`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "term": {"item": "abc"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "range" : {
                    "postDate" : {
                        "from" : "2010-03-01",
                        "to" : "2010-04-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`   . what different between `filter not` and `must_not` ?

Comment: See my comment above, `not` is deprecated in 2.1, you're still free to use it of course, but you should use `must_not` instead.

Comment: No prob, glad to help!